# What is the penalty to dying inside Elder Tale?

Tags: log-horizon

When people die inside Elder Tale they respawn in the Cathedral.
In the first episode a penalty for dying was mentioned. However, no specifics were given.

Does the light novel or the manga shed some light on what the penalty (or penalties) might be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is covered later in the LNs (which are being translated and are available [here](http://www.baka-tsuki.org/project/index.php?title=Log_Horizon)):

- Adventurers lose EXP while NPCs die for real.
- However, there is an additional penalty that is not obvious: when an adventurer dies they lose some of their memories.

Major spoiler:

> If the cathedral is destroyed, adventurers cannot respawn and die for real.

Comment: I took the risk, and read the major spoiler. lol :P thanks for the answer

Comment: @JNat I added a link to the translated LNs as well

Answer (score 1):

The newest episode states: resurrection will cause a loss of EXP.

My guess for dying:

- (the same)
- people can take your stuff
- takes time to "come back to life"
- you lose part of your equipment

Comment: You do not lose your equipment upon death. During one of the early scenes with the bandits, the bandits are forcing characters to strip off their armor at knife-point because if it is not unequipped before death they will keep it.